# "Eclipse XSL Developer Tools" support for XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1

Tags: eclipse, xslt, eclipse-wtp

I wonder whether there is a plan about Eclipse WTP supporting XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1 spec.

Clicked around for a while in [webtools site](https://download.eclipse.org/webtools) and [PsychoPath XPath 2.0 Processor](https://wiki.eclipse.org/PsychoPathXPathProcessor), but could not find any hint, when 3.0 specification of XSLT and 3.1 of XPath will be supported - e.g. syntax highlighting and failure indications. So far XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 was good enough for me, but it changes.

Comment: I don't know much about Eclipse but I think the oXygen XML editor which by now has been updated to support XPath 3.1 and XSLT 3.0 provides some kind of plugin for Eclipse. In general, if an editor supports using an XML schema for XML element/attribute suggestions/completions, you could try to use the schema for XSLT 3 that the spec contains.

Comment: Other editors with XSLT 3 and/or XPath 3.1 supports are Visual Studio Code with the "XSLT/XPath for Visual Studio Code" extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deltaxml.xslt-xpath and 
IntelliJ IDEA with the plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8612-xquery-intellij-plugin

Comment: Yes, XSLT 3.0 support is missing in WTP. Do you want to contribute it? As a Java developer and knowing XSLT 3.0, you seem to have the necessary skills to do this.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Asking to recommend a tool is off-topic on Stack Overflow, so please do not recommend tools, especially if it was not asked and if some tools are commercial tools. Please support open source instead.

Comment: investigated [XSLT Project](https://wiki.eclipse.org/XSLT_Project) for a while to get a feeling what it would mean to contribute - but I got nowhere, would need help.